# Elements that should be above video is under video

Tags: html, css

https://codepen.io/smellypotato/pen/jObKOEx

```
<style>
  #videoSlider {
    appearance: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    bottom: 4%;
    width: 96%;
    height: 3%;
    background: #888888;
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 10px;

  }

  #videoSlider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #CCCCCC;
    border-radius: 50%;
  }
  #videoSlider::-moz-range-thumb {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #CCCCCC;
    border-radius: 50%;
  }
</style>
<div style="width: 1180px; height: 664px; overflow: hidden; transform-origin: left top; position: absolute; transform: scale(0.32563405797101447, 0.32563405797101447) rotate(90deg); left: 344.5244565217391px;" id="videoBox">
<video autoplay="true" muted="true" display="none" webkit-playsinline="true" playsinline="true"id="" style="width: 100%; height: auto; top: 5%;" touch-action="none" src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4"></video>
<input type="range" min="0" id="videoSlider" max="42.077">
</div>
```

In the codepen link, I have a outer div containing a video and a range input. The outer div is rotated 90deg (for specific usage on mobile device which cannot be change), and overflow is set to hidden (because video can be enlarged but need to keep it inside the div so cannot change too). The video has a size same as the outer div, and the range input has a width same as the outer div.

Question: why the range input is not shown above the video? If you open inspector and remove the video, you can see the range input is in the right place (or you can highlight the range input to see its position)

What I have tested:

1. any elements put on top of the video have the same effect (such as div, input)
2. overflow: hidden affect. If other properties remain unchanged, changing overflow:hidden to other value or simply remove overflow:hidden will show the range input as normal
3. rotate(90deg) affect. If other properties remain unchanged, removing rotate(90deg) will show the range input as normal. Changing the deg to -47 to 70deg also can show the range input.

I have found an alternative way to solve this problem, but I want to know why this happen

Answer (score 0):

So your overflow should be visible, and you needed to make the position of the slider relative in #videoSlider.

```css
 #videoSlider {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    bottom: 5%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 3%;
    background: #888888;
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 10px;
   position: relative;
  }

  #videoSlider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #CCCCCC;
    border-radius: 50%;
  }
  #videoSlider::-moz-range-thumb {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #CCCCCC;
    border-radius: 50%;
  }
```

```html
<div style="width: 1180px; height: 664px; overflow: visible; transform-origin: left top; position: absolute; transform: scale(0.32563405797101447, 0.32563405797101447) rotate(90deg); left: 344.5244565217391px;" id="videoBox"><video autoplay="true" muted="true" display="none" webkit-playsinline="true" playsinline="true"id="" style="width: 100%; height: auto; top: 5%;" touch-action="none" src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4"></video><input type="range" min="0" id="videoSlider" max="42.077"></div>
```

Comment: did I not mention the overflow must be hidden?